# How to Get Description Field to Display with LinkedIn Share API

Tags: json, rest, linkedin-api

When I post this JSON to the Share API:

```
{
  "comment": "Here is my comment",
  "content": {
    "title": "Here is my title",
    "description": "Description:  The picture will be of a blue and gold macaw",
    "submitted-url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macaw",  
    "submitted-image-url": "http://yourshot.nationalgeographic.com/u/ss/fQYSUbVfts-T7pS2VP2wnKyN8wxywmXtY0-FwsgxoJBD4C1qJrqA8EfaP7jL8gZYg0MJlb9NNBxrHhmaSdwF/"
  },
  "visibility": {
    "code": "anyone"
  }  
}
```

I see this in the Activity:

[image]

What I don't see is the content in the description field.  I did not write our original integration to this, but my project manager claims that the LinkedIn UI originally showed these descriptions.  Has something changed?  Are we doing something wrong?

UPDATE:

I just noticed a similar question here:

[Share On LinkedIn Description field not displayed in new UI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42726277/328184)

I'm actually not sure what I should do from an SO perspective since I provided extra content that I think would be helpful in identifying the problem.

Comment: Hey, I know this post is four years old by now, but any thoughts on accepting an answer maybe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have spent two weeks talking with the LinkedIn support staff and developers about this problem.  *[Oh the humanity...](https://www.revoltlib.com/linkedin-social-share-url-broken-ticket.html)*  Succinct summary...

- If you have an image defined (using `og:image` or API), ***then no description will display in share preview.***
- If you have no image defined (using `og:image` or API), but you have a description defined (using `og:description` tag or API), ***then description will display in share preview.***

Easiest way to test?  GitHub has an `og:image` tag, but Wikipedia does not have an `og:image` tag.  What do they look like in social sharing in LinkedIn?

[image]
[image]

**Wikipedia:** [No `og:image` tag, but `og:description` displays.](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikipedia.org%2F)
**GitHub:** [Yes `og:image` tag, but no `og:description` displays.](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.github.com%2F)

I also went through the hassle of making a super simple demo to test this hypothesis...

[**Working LinkedIn Share Link Demo Without `og:image` Tags**](https://www.revoltlib.com/linkedin-social-share-url-test.html):

```
<HTML><HEAD>
    <meta property="og:title" content="LinkedIn Share URL Test">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Testing description!">
    <meta property='og:url' content="https://www.revoltlib.com/linkedin-social-share-url-test.html"/>
</HEAD><BODY>This page has no og:image tag.</BODY></HTML>
```

You shouldn't need to have trouble finding a site ***with*** `og:image` tags, basically every site seems to have it!

After thorough testing, it seems to check out!  I'm well aware that the [Official Microsoft LinkedIn Share Documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en) makes no mention whatsoever of this, but all of the real evidence seems to point in the opposite direction.

Comment: This is the answer! Very difficult to find this information elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks i have the same error! Really, love you hahaha

Answer (score 1):

What I found out playing with the api is that the description field is only shown if an image is not provided.
While you can ommit the `submitted-image-url` property the linkedin crawler will place an image to the post if it finds in the meta of the page.

With this api call:

```
{
  "comment": "Here is my comment",
  "content": {
    "title": "Here is my title",
    "description": "Description:  The picture will be of a blue and gold macaw",
    "submitted-url": "https://developer.microsoft.com/hu-hu/"
  },
  "visibility": {
    "code": "anyone"
  }  
}
```

I could produce this post:
[image: linkedin post with description]

Honestly I think this is a bug in there renderer.

Comment: Hello, are you able to add description even the page meta has image? having the same issue as yours :(

Comment: As far as I remember I couldn't back then. Haven't tried that for a while.

Answer (score 0):

It´s all about the size of the image. If it´s large, LinkedIn shows only the image (it becomes an image sharing). If it´s tiny, LinkedIn creates an actual article share, with a kind of card, with the text and image like an icon.
[the linkedin card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5VQI.png)

Comment: ideally, 138x72